# Match groups in comma-delimited list, ignoring commas in brackets

Tags: java, regex, coldfusion

I am working with the following string:

```
required,something_here[arg1,arg2],hey_yo[abc=123], is_date,date_after[date1,date2]
```

My goal is to match the groups where they are separated by the comma, but ignore the comma within the brackets. The end result would be:

```
required
something_here[arg1,arg2]
hey_yo[abc=123]
is_date
date_after[date1,date2]
```

So far, I have been able to match the commas correctly. However, it's the inverse of what I actually need. The regular expression I've been using is:

```
(,(?![^\[]*]))
```

Any suggestions on how I can rewrite this to obtain the inverse of my current results?

http://regexr.com/39tb0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, here you go:

```regex
(?:[^\]\[,]+|\[[^\]\[]+\])+
```

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/qX3gE5/2). You can find with the pattern matching:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:[^\\]\\[,]+|\\[[^\\]\\[]+]\])+");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
```

This matches all sequences which doesn't contain commas or square brackets. When we come upon square brackets, the group alternates to the right hand side, which matches everything between the square brackets, and returns to the left hand side for matching everything up to the next comma, rinse and repeat, effectively asserting matches without coming upon a disqualifying comma.

Here is a [jdoodle code demo](http://jdoodle.com/a/gq).

Comment: Thank you! This solution is perfect, even on the larger test scenarios. Also nice that it doesn't capture the group where the brackets are empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this lookahead based regex:

```
,(?![^\]\[]*\])
```

#### [RegEx Demo](http://regex101.com/r/nQ5iO7/2)

`(?![^\]\[]*\])` is negative lookahead that will make sure that comma is not inside `[` and `]` by making sure comma is not followed by "0 or more non-square bracket characters followed by `]`".

Answer (score 1):

To find items without leading and trailing spaces, and to allow empty items, you can use this:

```
(?=[^\s,])(?: ?[^[\s,]+|\[[^]]*])*|(?<=,|^)(?=\s*(?:,|$))
```

Answer (score 1):

How's this method?

```
(?:([^,\[]*\[[^\]]*\])(?:,|$))|([^,\[\]]+(?:,|$))
```

http://regexr.com/39tbr

The pattern is made up of two alternative pattern matches, one with the brackets and one without.
This also uses non-capturing groups ?: for anchoring matches and grouping.
But the two capturing groups should match what you are looking for.

Reading left to right:

1. match anything except for a comma or open bracket, greedy match
2. match an option bracket
3. match anything except for a close bracket
4. match a comma or end of line
5. OR
6. match anything except for a commあ or open bracket, at least one character, greedy match
7. match a comma or end of line

Comment: The abundancy can be reduced by making the square bracket group optional.

Answer (score 1):

Just tossing this in here because I wanted to see what I could come up with

```
([^,]+\[[^\],]*,[^\],]*\]|[^,]+)
```